# Split a column and get string between parantheses

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has a column called Summary and each row looks like this:

```
[AB][Hello][MM_BM_00][WBATR550A54333]    
(Trigger)[CD][VSI][LL_BM_00][WBAKS410205872]    
(CL-CAPA)[Map][CAPA][LI_BM_00][X4X79420WB527]    
[CD][VSK][KK_BM_00][WBAKS8V59455][X]
```

So the text somethimes starts with square brackets as in row 1 *- [AB]*,  and sometimes with round brackets as in row 2 - *(Trigger)*.
After the split, I want the string between () to be in the the first column and the rows which do not start with () should have Null value.

So the end result should look like this:

[image]

Could someone help? I am super new to Python

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello, please revise your question with the expected output and the code you have tried with. Provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to aid you. Please review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for a quicker response.

Comment: Please don’t share information as images unless absolutely necessary, which isn’t the case here. Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: You should include the python code you mention. The table would be much more useful for those seeking to help you, if you included the table as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.Series(['[AB][Hello][MM_BM_00][WBATR550A54333]',
               '(Trigger)[CD][VSI][LL_BM_00][WBAKS410205872]',
               '(CL-CAPA)[Map][CAPA][LI_BM_00][X4X79420WB527]',
               '[CD][VSK][KK_BM_00][WBAKS8V59455][X]'])

result = (df.str.replace('\]|\(|\)', '')
            .str.split('\[', expand=True)
            .replace('', np.nan)
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have been more clear but I have thousands of rows and I just pasted the first 4 rows here to show how the column looks like. Can you write a dynamic code?